# how to print out the data at the certain line using bash script?

Tags: file, bash

I have a txt file with 100k lines. If I want to know what is the data at line #24356 looks like, how can I do that in the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` can print line ranges specified,so in this case it will be `sed -n 24356,24356p $FILE`

Comment: Another good one. Keep in mind, for a _single_ line, you can just do `sed -n 24356p input_file`.

Comment: Once you've reached the line, there's no point reading on! `sed '24356!d;q'`

Answer (score 3):

You can get a specific line with `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==24356{print;exit}' input_file
```

That will print the line and exit as soon as the record number `NR` is what you desire, otherwise it will do nothing. The `exit` is to ensure that you don't process lines unnecessarily after the one you're interested in.

For example, see the following transcript:

```
pax> cat qq.sh
while read line
do
    echo "Reading within the loop: [$line]"
    echo -n "What do you want to say? "
    read -u 3 something
    echo "You input: [$something]"
done 3<&0 <qq.sh

pax> awk 'NR==2{print;exit}' qq.sh
do

pax> awk 'NR==3{print;exit}' qq.sh
    echo "Reading within the loop: [$line]"
```

Comment: The default to print will only occur if you provide a condition that evaluates to true. This suffices: `awk 'NR==24356' file`

Comment: No need to read after you've reached the line you want. `awk 'NR==24356{print;exit}'`

Comment: Both good points, guys. I've incorporated them into the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
cat filename | head -24356 | tail -1
```

commands used should be available on every *nix system

Comment: Or save yourself a process and use `head -23456 filename | tail -1`, though I have to admit I'll often start pipelines with `cat` as well since it's easier than remembering which commands can take a filename and which just want standard input :-)